# Replacing pattern inside html parameter

Tags: regex, linux, sed

I want to replace this

```
href="//noname.com/basil/armada/joke.pdf" href="//noname.com/family/hello.pdf"
```

with

```
href="//noname.com/arid/joke.pdf" href="//noname.com/arid/hello.pdf"
```

-This is just a pseudo-code for a huge file I'm working with so I can't do it by hand. 
-And everything is in 1 line, so I believe all I can use is the substitute command
-Is this even possible with sed?

I've tried

```
sed '/href/s#//noname.com.*(armada|family)?#//noname.com/arid#g' < list.html > list2.html
```

but nothing gets replaced.... ?

I'm using GNU sed version 4.7

Comment: @Tiw Updated it to include the sed version

Comment: You are using alternatives `armada|family` of extended regular expressions. Therefore you need to use the `-r` flag.

Comment: see also: https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#BRE-vs-ERE and I would suggest to use `-E` instead of `-r` as that is more portable these days

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `GNU sed`:

```
$ echo 'href="//noname.com/basil/armada/joke.pdf" href="//noname.com/family/hello.pdf" ' | sed -r '/href/s#//noname.com/(basil/armada|family)#//noname.com/arid#g'
href="//noname.com/arid/joke.pdf" href="//noname.com/arid/hello.pdf"
```

You can use `-E` or `-r` in this case. (`-E` more compatible across systems)
Also you forgot `basil/`...
Check `sed --help` or `man sed` for more.

*Update*, how about like this:

```
$ echo 'href="//noname.com/basil/armada/joke.pdf" href="//noname.com/family/hello.pdf" ' | sed -r '/href="..noname.com/s#(armada|family)#arid#g'
href="//noname.com/basil/arid/joke.pdf" href="//noname.com/arid/hello.pdf"
```

You can change the `..` to `\/\/` for accuracy.

**If you don't want to keep the `basil` part...**
Your command in comment leaves only one url is because of regex's **greedy** mode, check this:

```
$ echo 'href="//noname.com/basil/armada/joke.pdf" href="//noname.com/family/hello.pdf" ' | sed -r '/href/s#href....noname.com/(.*)(armada|family).*#\1#g'
basil/armada/joke.pdf" href="//noname.com/
```

You can see, the `.*` actually captured first `basil` to before the **next** `family`.
So we need to find a way to stop regex being too greedy, for example:

```
$ echo 'href="//noname.com/basil/armada/joke.pdf" href="//noname.com/family/hello.pdf" ' | sed -r '/href/s#//noname.com/[^.]*(armada|family)#//noname.com/arid#g'
href="//noname.com/arid/joke.pdf" href="//noname.com/arid/hello.pdf"
```

The `[^.]` means any character that is not a `.`, in this case to avoid the regex to match beyond the `.` before `pdf`, as a stop mark.
You may need find another anchor in other cases.
Check more [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html).

Comment: I also had ``` .* ``` to make up for that ```basil/``` because in the actual file there's something very long in between. Not just ```basil/```

Comment: Like, understand it

Comment: Sorry, first time using stackoverflow

Comment: Using `echo 'href="//noname.com/basil/armada/joke.pdf" href="//noname.com/family/hello.pdf" ' | sed -E '/href/s#//noname.com/.*(armada|family)#//noname.com/arid#g' 
href="//noname.com/arid/hello.pdf"` works for the last href but deletes the first

Comment: I don't want `basil` in the output. I under the impression that I NEED to use `.*`. Is there any way we can do it where we use `.*` @Tiw

Comment: Check again. @RubenDario